# Similarity between two arrays with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy

A = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
B = [2.1, 3.2, 5.1, 6.1]

The above two arrays A and B have different lengths. The arrays are considered ordered and the actual two arrays are both more than 500 rows. I was trying to find a metric to compare the similarity. The correlation, Discrete Fréchet distance, cosine similarity, etc require the same dimension which is not suitable in this case. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very well defined problem since there are many different ways to define "closeness". One immediate issue is whether the arrays are ordered, or just sets of numbers?

One approach that ignores order is to compute properties of the arrays, such as mean and several norms (basically moments of the data), and then compare those properties, which will be the same length.  For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

A = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
B = [2.1, 3.2, 5.1, 6.1]
mean_A = np.mean(A)
len_A = len(A)
mean_B = np.mean(B)
len_B = len(B)
signature_A = np.array([mean_A, np.linalg.norm(A - mean_A, 1) / len(A), np.linalg.norm(A - mean_A, 2) / math.sqrt(len_A)])
signature_B = np.array([mean_B, np.linalg.norm(B - mean_B, 1) / len(B), np.linalg.norm(B - mean_B, 2) / math.sqrt(len_B)])
how_close = np.linalg.norm(signature_A - signature_B)
```

The normalization by `len_A` and `len_B` is to make vectors like this be "close":

```py
A = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
B = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
```

If you don't want those vectors to be considered "close" them remove the normalization by `len_A` and `len_B`.

You could add higher-level norms (ie, n > 2, or the infinity norm, or min/max) or other attributes of the data . The infinity norm (or min/max) might not be a good attribute since it only depends on as few as one (or two for min/max) values in the array.  You might need to scale each attribute so one that happens to have large or small values doesn't dominate or isn't ignored.  For example, how important is the min/max (or infinity norm) attribute?  You can scale that accordingly.

If instead the arrays are considered ordered, then one approach could be to fit a curve (eg, polynomial) to each array, using linearly spaced x-axis samples between 0 and 1.  You could then compare the coefficients of each fit.  However, this will quickly break down on large vectors, and you'll have to address the issue of over or under fitting.

Comment: Hi @craigb , The arrays are considered ordered and the actual two arrays are both more than 500 rows.

Comment: Hmmm, that is more difficult, especially without knowing whether the index into the array has meaning or is comparable between the two arrays.  If it is meaningful, then perhaps you could interpolate the shorter one.  But that's only useful if nearby elements are correlated.  Failing that, you'll need to figure out what "closeness" means for ordered arrays when there isn't some connected attribute.